# Lower bound on the size of maximum interval induced subgraphs of an $n$-vertex graph $G$

Tags: reference-request, extremal-combinatorics, interval-graphs

Let $H$ be a maximum induced interval subgraph of a graph $G=(V,E)$.  If $n=|V|$， then what is the smallest number of $V(H)$?

The number is at most $3n/4$： consider a set of disjoint $4$-holes.

Can it be smaller?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the answer is $\Theta(\log n)$ and the proof is the same as the classic Ramsey-theorem proof. On one hand, you always have a complete or empty subgraph with these many vertices. On the other, a random graph won't have a large induced $C_4$-free subgraph. For this latter, bound the number of induced subgraphs on $t$ vertices by $n^t$ and for each bound the probability of being $C_4$-free by $c^{t^2}$ where $c<1$ is some constant. This we can do because a complete graph on $t$ vertices contains $\Omega(t^2)$ disjoint $K_4$'s.

In more detail, divide the $t\choose 2$ possible edges among any $t$ vertices into $\Omega(t^2)$ disjoint cliques of four vertices. In any such clique of four vertices, the probability that the edges among them will not form a $C_4$ is some constant $p<1$. Therefore the probability that there won't be a $C_4$ in any of the cliques is $p^{\Omega(t^2)}$. This is clearly an upper bound for the random graph to be $C_4$-free.

Comment: Great!  Can you elaborate?  I've been trying this approach but my probabilistic tools are kind of rusty.

Comment: Which part? The proof follows step by step the famous proof of Erdos: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_method#First_example

Comment: The part where we have to bound the probability of subgraph $H$ on $t$ vertices being $C_4$-free; in particular, I do not know how to bound this by $c^{t^2}$.  Also I don't understand the relation between the last sentence and the second last sentence.

Comment: Ah, *edge* disjoint 4-cliques.  You are right.  Thanks for the explanation!  @Yixin: I think domotorp has a much better answer.  You should accept his instead of mine.

Answer (score 6):

We can do $2\sqrt{n}-1$; consider the complete $\sqrt{n}$-partite graph, as long as there are two parties both with more than one node inside there is an induced $C_4$, so it cannot be inteval.  Therefore we have to remove at least $(\sqrt{n}-1)^2 = n - 2\sqrt{n} + 1$ nodes to destroy all the induced $C_4$.

Comment: Great! Can we go further to show this is the lower bound?  It really looks one.   P.S. I'll mark this as an answer if no better answers appear.